# Connecting Wii to router to Proxy Server via VPN to BBC iPlayer

Tags: networking

I live in the USA and want to be able to watch UK TV streamed over the web. The relevant services are geographically crippled. I can do this by using a VPN proxy server in the UK, connecting to the VPN service using a straight Windows VPN connection. However, this means I have to watch everything on my PC.

The BBC iPlayer works on the Wii in the UK. So, I'd like to connect my Wii to a wireless router (LinkSys WRT54G2) and have that be automatically connected via VPN to my proxy service in the UK. If I can do this then I'd be able to stream UK TV direct to my TV via the Wii.

I thought I could have one router act as my VPN connection, connected to a 2nd router that connects to my Cable internet access. But this bit isn't working, any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately, Superuser doesn't allow any video game or console related content either.

Comment: You need a UK TV licence in order to watch content from BBC iPlayer (i.e. you need to reside in the UK.)  Without it, you would be breaking the law.

Comment: I have a UK TV Licence, I live ~6 months a year in UK and the other in US. I want the convenience of continuing to watch shows whilst in US.

Comment: @Josh; It's PURELY videogame related. This has nothing to do with video games.

Answer (score 1):

use tvproxy.co.uk - this works brilliantly. I live in the states too and never have had a problem with it. Simple set up too

Answer (score 0):

If you flash your router with something like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), you can have the router hold the [VPN connection](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VPN) open for you.

Have no idea about the legality of connecting to a UK site from the US to use something that's geographically-bound, but the VPN aspect is legal :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a proxy server located in UK, you would just need to to configure internet connection in wii settings to use proxy server, it is fairly easy to do.